# How to instantiate constructor with dynamic value and Autowire it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor, autowired, spring-annotations

I have instantiated a parametrized constructor here called request operation with dynamic values. how to @Autowire this to Requestclass? subsequently, in Request class, I have created a **new RatingResponse** how to @Autowire this as well?

**class Initializer**

```
public class Intializer
{ 
NewClass newclass = new NewClass();
String testName = Number + "_" + "Test"; -->getting the String number dynamically
Test test = new Test(testName); -> this is  a different class 

Operation operation = new RequestOperation(test, newclass  , 
                  sxxx, yyy, zzz); - argumented constructor
opertaion.perform();
}
```

**RequestClass**

```
public class RequestOperation implements Operation { 

// the constructor 
public RequestOperation(Test test, Sheet reportSheet, XElement element, TestDataManager testDataManager, Report report) 
{       
this.test = test;
this.newclass  = newclass  ;
this.sxxx= sxxx;
this.yyy= yyy;
this.zzz= zzz; 
    } 
    @Override   
public boolean perform(String CompanyName, String Province) {
Response response = new RatingResponse(this.test, this.reportSheet,
callService(this.buildRequest(CompanyName, Province)), this, this.report);-> create a new paramterizedconstructor
    } 

private String buildRequest(String CompanyName, String Province) { 
return pm.getAppProperties().getProperty(constructedValue); }
    }
```

**Response class **

```
    public class RatingResponse implements Response {
    public RatingResponse(Test test, Sheet reportSheet, Object obj, RequestOperation requestOperation, Report report) {
this.test = test;
if (obj instanceof Document) {
this.document = (Document) obj;
}
this.operation = requestOperation;
this.reportSheet = reportSheet;
this.report = report;
}
```

** interface **

```
@Component
public interface Operation {    
    public boolean perform(String Name, String Province);
    }

@Component
public interface Response {

    void construct();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot, you can autowire only types marked with @Bean or classes marked with @Component or its derivitives like @Service, @Controller

The speciality of these annotations is that only a single instance of the class is kept in memory.

So if your requirement needs you to create new classes for each set of new dynamic values, then autowiring them is not the right way to go.

However if you have limited number of possible dynamic values that your class can have, you can create beans for each of them like this

```
@Configuration
class MyBeans{

    @Bean
    public RatingResponse ratingResponse(){

        Response response = new RatingResponse(this.test, this.reportSheet,
        callService(this.buildRequest(CompanyName, Province)), this, this.report);
        return response
    }

}
```

Then in the class you need to use it, you can do

```
@Autowired 
RatingResponse ratingResponse
```

Comment: how should I get the value of test, reportsheet  etc in MyBeans